# How to convert mp4 to HLS and add subtitles to master playlist with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to use `ffmpeg` to convert an `mp4` file to `HLS`, add subtitles, and have them in the `master playlist`.

I managed to get it to create `index_vtt.m3u8` files that contain the subtitles, but it doesn't want to add the stream to the `master playlist`.
I'm new to this so I don't fully understand how the whole ffmpeg works (I'm mainly just trying out bunch of resources I found on the net)

I'm using the following command:

```
../ffmpeg-4.2.1/ffmpeg -i ../input.mp4 -i ../subtitile.vtt -c:s webvtt -profile:v baseline -level 21 -s 1280x720 -start_number 0 -hls_playlist_type vod -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 3 -f hls -master_pl_name master.m3u8 index.m3u8`
```

It generates `master.m3u8`

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=140800,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.42c015,mp4a.40.2"
index.m3u8
```

I can play it in vlc, but it doesn't recognize any subtitles.
Then I modify the `master.m3u8` so it looks like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,URI="index_vtt.m3u8",GROUP-ID="default-text-group",LANGUAGE="hr",NAME="Croatian",AUTOSELECT=YES

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=140800,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.42c01e,mp4a.40.2",SUBTITLES="default-text-group"
index.m3u8
```

And everything is fine. How can I tell `ffmpeg` to do this for me?

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to use the `-hls_flags` option with `single_file` to make sure the subtitles are included in a single `.vtt` file, and you also need to specify the `-var_stream_map` option to map the video, audio, and subtitle streams to the HLS playlists.

Look at this example:

```bash
../ffmpeg-4.2.1/ffmpeg \
-i ../input.mp4 \
-i ../subtitile.vtt \
-c:v copy \
-c:a copy \
-c:s webvtt \
-profile:v baseline \
-level 21 \
-s 1280x720 \
-start_number 0 \
-hls_playlist_type vod \
-hls_time 10 \
-hls_list_size 0 \
-hls_flags single_file \
-var_stream_map "v:0,a:0,s:0" \
-master_pl_name master.m3u8 \
-f hls index.m3u8
```

Here's the explanation:

1. `-c:v copy` and `-c:a copy` have been added to ensure the video and audio are just copied without re-encoding.
2. `-var_stream_map` is used to map the video, audio, and subtitle streams to the HLS playlists.
3. `-hls_list_size 0` ensures that all segments are included in the playlist.
4. `-hls_flags single_file` ensures that the subtitles are included in a single `.vtt` file.

I think this command generates the necessary master playlist (master.m3u8) that includes the subtitles, similar to what you manually edited.